# Change the format of json output in through mongoose

Tags: mongoose, merge, field

I have a data in **mongoose** which has arrays.

The result is below

```
[{ first_name: 'Micheal', last_name: 'Smith'},  _id: 5b9896d308925c0f5cd866ff,  team:    [ { name: 'swift', color: 'yellow'} ] ,     
{ first_name: 'Evelyn',last_name: 'Nestor'},  _id: 5b9897ea08925c0f5cd86740,  team:    [ { name: 'amethyst', color: 'pink'} ] ,     
{ first_name: 'Favour',last_name: 'Polish'},  _id: 5b98987f08925c0f5cd86780,  team:    [ { name: 'laser', color: 'green'} ] ,     
{ first_name: 'Winney',last_name: 'Marek'},  _id: 5b98991508925c0f5cd867c0,  team:    [ { name: 'jade', color: 'blue'} ] }]
```

I want to merge everything ( if possible within mongoose) , so that it looks like this

```
[{ first_name: 'Micheal', last_name: 'Smith',name: 'swift', color: 'yellow',_id: 5b9896d308925c0f5cd866ff }  ,     
{ first_name: 'Evelyn',last_name: 'Nestor', name: 'amethyst', color: 'pink',  _id: 5b9897ea08925c0f5cd86740},     
{ first_name: 'Favour',last_name: 'Polish', name: 'laser', color: 'green', _id: 5b98987f08925c0f5cd86780},     
{ first_name: 'Winney',last_name: 'Marek', name: 'jade', color: 'blue', _id: 5b98991508925c0f5cd867c0}]
```

Comment: "*I have a data in mongoose*". That is not possible as your example is invalid. Please add the correct structure.

Comment: `team` contains only single element inside the array?